# Extracting Text from PDF - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have code that was written for me and it works perfect for four of the entries     I am wanting to find, but is there a way that I can add another field value to search for, like ID? I have tried to change the code for what I think would work, but I got errors. I have never coded something this complex, so I do not understand fully what the author did in each section.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub ExtractFieldValues()

  Const CONSTLAST   As Long = 1
  Const CONSTFIRST  As Long = 2
  Const CONSTMIDDLE As Long = 3
  Const CONSTRANK   As Long = 4
  Const TABLEONE     As String = "Table 1"
  Const FIELDVALUES As String = "FieldValues"
  Const LAST_FIRST_MIDDLE As String = "last first middle"
  Const FIELDNAMES        As String = LAST_FIRST_MIDDLE & " rank"
  Const NUMRECORDS As Long = 5 '6

  Dim ƒ As Excel.WorksheetFunction: Set ƒ = Excel.WorksheetFunction
  Dim ¡ As Long
  Dim lrd As Long
  Dim nextRowOutput As Long
  Dim arngFoundCells(CONSTLAST To CONSTRANK) As Range
  Dim varFoundCell As Variant
  Dim lngFirstFoundRow As Long
  Dim lngNextFoundRow As Long
  Dim rngNextFindStart As Range
  Dim dictFields As Object
  Dim astrFieldNames() As String
  Dim astrSplitValues() As String
  Dim strFoundValue As String
  Dim lngFieldCount As Long


Set dictFields = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dictFields.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

  With Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
    .Add(After:=.Item(.count)).name = FIELDVALUES
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      If .Item(.count).name <> FIELDVALUES Then
        .Item(.count).Delete
        .Item(FIELDVALUES).UsedRange.Clear
      End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    .Item(TABLEONE).Activate
  End With

  astrFieldNames = Split(" " & FIELDNAMES, " ") ' Force index zero to a blank -> treat as base 1
  Set dictFields = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  For ¡ = CONSTLAST To CONSTRANK
    dictFields.Add astrFieldNames(¡), ""
  Next ¡
  lrd _
  = Cells _
  .find _
      ( _
      What:="*" _
      , After:=Cells(1) _
      , LookIn:=xlFormulas _
      , Lookat:=xlPart _
      , SearchOrder:=xlByRows _
      , SearchDirection:=xlPrevious _
      ) _
 .Row

  With Range(Rows(1), Rows(lrd))

    For ¡ = CONSTLAST To CONSTRANK
      Set arngFoundCells(¡) = .find(What:=astrFieldNames(¡), After:=Cells(1))
    Next ¡
    lngFirstFoundRow _
= ƒ.Min _
    ( _
      arngFoundCells(CONSTLAST).Row _
    , arngFoundCells(CONSTFIRST).Row _
    , arngFoundCells(CONSTMIDDLE).Row _
    )
nextRowOutput = 1

Do
  For ¡ = CONSTLAST To CONSTRANK
'        Debug.Print arngFoundCells(¡).Address; " ";
        dictFields.Item(astrFieldNames(¡)) = ""
  Next ¡
'      Debug.Print
      Select Case True
        Case arngFoundCells(CONSTFIRST).Row = arngFoundCells(CONSTMIDDLE).Row:
          If arngFoundCells(CONSTRANK).Row <> arngFoundCells(CONSTFIRST).Row     Then
        Set arngFoundCells(CONSTRANK) = arngFoundCells(CONSTFIRST)
      End If
      For Each varFoundCell In arngFoundCells
        strFoundValue = ƒ.Trim(Replace(varFoundCell.Value2, vbLf, " ")) & " "
        If strFoundValue Like "[']*" Then strFoundValue = Mid$(strFoundValue, 2)
        If LCase$(strFoundValue) Like astrFieldNames(CONSTLAST) & " " Then
          strFoundValue = ƒ.Trim(strFoundValue & Rows(varFoundCell.Row + 1).Cells(1).Value2) & " "
        End If
        If LCase$(strFoundValue) Like LAST_FIRST_MIDDLE & "*" _
        And Len(strFoundValue) - Len(Replace(strFoundValue, " ", "")) < 5 _
        Then
          strFoundValue = ƒ.Trim(strFoundValue & Rows(varFoundCell.Row + 1).Cells(1).Value2) & " "
        End If
        astrSplitValues = Split(" " & strFoundValue, " ") ' Force index zero to a blank -> treat as base 1
        lngFieldCount = Int(UBound(astrSplitValues) / 2)
        For ¡ = 1 To lngFieldCount
          dictFields.Item(LCase(astrSplitValues(¡))) = astrSplitValues(¡ + lngFieldCount)
        Next ¡
      Next varFoundCell
    Case Else
      Debug.Print "  SKIPPED: ";
      For ¡ = CONSTLAST To CONSTRANK
        Debug.Print arngFoundCells(¡).Address; " ";
      Next ¡
      Debug.Print
      For ¡ = CONSTLAST To CONSTRANK
        Debug.Print "    "; ƒ.Trim(arngFoundCells(¡).Value2)
      Next ¡
      Debug.Print
  End Select
  Sheets(FIELDVALUES).Columns(1).Cells(nextRowOutput).Resize(4).Value _
  = ƒ.Transpose(dictFields.Items)
  nextRowOutput = nextRowOutput + NUMRECORDS
  Set rngNextFindStart = Rows(arngFoundCells(CONSTFIRST).Row + 2).Cells(1)
  For ¡ = CONSTLAST To CONSTRANK
    Set arngFoundCells(¡) = .find(What:=astrFieldNames(¡), After:=rngNextFindStart)
  Next ¡
  lngNextFoundRow _
  = ƒ.Min _
      ( _
        arngFoundCells(CONSTLAST).Row _
      , arngFoundCells(CONSTFIRST).Row _
      , arngFoundCells(CONSTMIDDLE).Row _
      )
Loop While lngNextFoundRow <> lngFirstFoundRow

  End With

End Sub
```